# How do I compile an SQL Cobol with || operator?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, cobol

I'm trying to compile an SQLCobol source on a As400 system containing a statement with `||` (as a concat operator).

Even if IBM DB2 rules admit the `||` operator, my program compilation fails.
I don't know if there is a compilation parameter to set. Can anyone help me?

Example of my code:

```
EXEC SQL                                                    
  INSERT INTO TABLEB                           
    (SELECT FIELD1 || " " || FIELD2  
       FROM TABLEA)                                       
END-EXEC.
```

The compilation error is

> Token | not valid

Thanks to everyone

Comment: I'd expect it to work, but if you can't find why it doesn't, use CONCAT() as a workaround. I.e. `CONCAT(FIELD1, CONCAT(" ", FIELD2))`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a code page issue with your terminal setup. The pipe symbol `|` the compiler wants, may be the broken bar `¦`, ot the exclamation point `!` on your keyboard. Try either `¦`, or `!` and see if one of these is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The `|` symbol is not one of the invariant characters in EBCDIC code pages.

You may be running into a translation issue or it may not even be available.

Best practice is to use the literal CONCAT operator.

```
EXEC SQL                                                    
  INSERT INTO TABLEB                           
    (SELECT FIELD1 concat ' ' concat FIELD2  
       FROM TABLEA)                                       
END-EXEC.
```

Comment: And then replace " with ' since " has special meaning to SQL.